# Action with parameter or parameter from router-store

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-router-store

Problem:

I have component and url such as:

`https://127.0.0.0/car/carName1/view1`

and

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.store$.dispatch(Actions.loadView());    
  }
```

This dispatch action, and effect gets single view from the service and add it to collection

state will look like this:

```
{
  views: {

     view1: {
        data: []
     }

     view2: {
        data: []
     }
  }
}
```

Now, inside same component I need to fetch more from view which contains more data I need, or in other words I need to select some that from it

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.data$ = this.store$.select(Selectors.selectMoreData);
        this.store$.dispatch(Actions.loadView());    
      }
```

Problem is that `Selectors.selectMoreData` needs view name/key.
Because state has more views than just one single for current component.

What possibilities I have? Like in effects use router-store and get key from url? Or should I step back because this is totally wrong.

Comment: How do you determine if a view belongs to a component? Does the component have some unique property ?

Comment: Right, and when multiple components take the url at the same time, how do you determine which should display the view?

Comment: Component is only container that render view in it, so when url is the same and have multiple components then all display the same. view is let say dynamic layout description taken from database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

After discussion in comments my answer would be the next one: do everything in `ngOnInit` to avoid complexity of passing variables here and there.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$ = this.store$.select(Selectors.selectMoreData, this.viewName);
  this.store$.dispatch(Actions.loadView());    
}
```

or in case of `router-store`

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$ = this.store$.pipe(
    select(selectRouteParam('viewName')),
    switchMap(viewName => combineLatest([
      of(viewName),
      this.store$.select(Selectors.selectMoreData, this.viewName)),
    ]),
    map(([viewName, data]) => ({viewName, data}));
  );

  this.store$.dispatch(Actions.loadView());    
}
```

and in template

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="data$ | async as data">
  <child [view]="data.viewName" [data]="data.data"></child>
</ng-container>
```

or in case of `this.activatedRoute`

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.data$ = this.activatedRoute.paramMap.pipe(
    map(params => params.get('viewName')),
    switchMap(viewName => combineLatest([
      of(viewName),
      this.store$.select(Selectors.selectMoreData, this.viewName)),
    ]),
    map(([viewName, data]) => ({viewName, data}));
  );

  this.store$.dispatch(Actions.loadView());    
}
```

**ORIGINAL**

You miss the 3rd option - to use a resolver that would provider data for your component in `ActivatedRoute.data`, you can find an example in the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61836566/13112018.

---

Besides that back to `viewName`. You can add it as route's data and then it will be accessible in the `router-store` too.

For example you can define a route like that.

```js
{
    path: 'test',
    component: TestComponent,
    data: {
        viewName: 'test',
    },
},
```

and then to use `router-store` to select it

```js
this.store.select(selectRouteData).subscribe(console.log); // {viewName: 'test'}
```

Comment: 3rd option is my first point. I thought that router-store is better idea.

Comment: I cannot put viewName inside router because it is something dynamic fetched from db

Comment: When do you fetch it? with every route or once per app / module load?

Comment: {views: View[]} are fetched in parent component. And sub component responsible for rendering needs single view so I need to provide a name of the view I currently have selected. Normally I would just set it in variable and pass to sub component

Comment: I see, in this case I would say don't make things complicated trying to pass it to resolver or anywhere else. Simply use ngOnInit to dispatch required actions and select all information from the store.

Comment: that's an example of I do: https://take.ms/j9kOJu one pipe in a component that fetches all info for the template.

Comment: thanks for answers. Regarding update - I probably cannot do just this.viewName? Its from the router so I should subscribe to it. This is why I created this question because I can subscribe to angular router and wait and in callback do this.store$ dispatch. But in that why use router-store.

Comment: I'm a bit confused - I see that `viewName` is a part of url in updated description. Nevertherless I've updated the answer to show how it could be done with `router-store` and child components.

Comment: Yes viewName is part of url so to take it from there I need to something like `this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(...)` not just use this.viewName. Nevertheless I think that router-store solution is what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: I see, you can simply use `withLatestfrom(this.activatedRoute.data)` in a pipe to get its value without subscription.

Comment: I added one more example in case of `this.activatedRoute`. How it helps :) Let me know if we need to discuss it further.